# What prerequisites does noncommutative geometry have?

Tags: soft-question, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I'm a Masters student currently deciding which area to focus on. So far, my primary interest has been $C^*$-algebras and operator algebras (I already have some knowledge of $K$-theory for $C^*$-algebras and Hilbert modules), but I always had some interest in geometry. When I learnt about the [Gelfand Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation), I thought there was a chance to mix both interests.

I tried to read Alain Connes' [*Noncommutative Geometry*](https://alainconnes.org/wp-content/uploads/book94bigpdf.pdf) and realized that I was missing lots of prerequisites. I'd like to have at least a broad enough picture of this area to determine whether I like it or not. What is the minimum I should know before I can do that?

Comment: Try reading this https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408416 There is also a book by the same author which is much friendlier than Connes' book. I'd say given that you already know some Operator algebras and K-theory, probably some algebraic topology and differential geometry is useful. Try understanding the Atiyah Singer index theorem statement.

Comment: I'm currently taking a course in diff geometry and took an introductory course for alg topology. Any book to study the Atiyah Singer index theorem?

Comment: Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators
Book by Ezra Getzler, Michèle Vergne, and Nicole Berline. The approach in this book is analytic. If you want a more K-theoretic approach there are two papers by Nigel Higson (One has K-theory in its name, the other deals with the tangemt groupoid) that you can google easily.

Comment: Elliot Natsume Nest offer a different approach via the "classical limit". Trying to understand all of these proofs will keep you busy for a while and it'll get you to learn a lot around noncommutative geometry.